# How to check if the column name is at the last or in the front of a string (python)?

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, position

I am new to pandas. I have an issue with knowing where the column is in last or first inside a string. For suppose I have a string `str = "000*999bikes"` where the bikes is a column name of df, now I want to check the position of the column whether it is in the first or last

My code:

```
str = "000*999bikes"
df =
  bikes cars
0  12    23
1  34    67
3  56    90
```

Now the column name bikes is in last of a string. How to know if it is in the last using if condition?

Comment: what's this got to do with the dataframe? where are the strr values coming from?

Comment: @forgetso it is given by the user. The program should check if the column name of df is in the last or first of that string

Comment: Can you give examples for both first and last? Would this be first? `000cars*999`

Comment: for first is this "cars000*999" and for last "000*999bikes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the number beside the column name, you can use the following code to check for each column.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[2,2]],columns=['bikes','cars'])

strings = ["cars000*999","000*999bikes"]

for s in strings:
    for col in df.columns:
        if s.startswith(col):
            print(col, s[len(col) + 1])
        if s.endswith(col):
            print(col, s[-len(col) - 1])
```

Output:

```
cars 0
bikes 9
```

If your strings are in the dataframe then you could do this with [pandas str operations](https://towardsdatascience.com/pandas-string-operations-explained-fdfab7602fb4?gi=909487d7e72b) instead of loops.

Comment: Thanks but what If I have "abcbikes" as a string ?

Comment: Like `000*999abcbikes` ? Then you'd need to use regular expressions.

Comment: Thanks For the help